# How to show dialog without pressing any button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Like at the start of the application of the app I want to open the dialogbox so that the user can enter the password and then only the application will proceed

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make another thread that accepts the user answers from the entry field and check if some condition achieved so that it stops the loop

you will make something like:

```
import threading
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from threading import Thread
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen

first_one = '''
MDTextField:
    id:ii
    pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
    size_hint_x:None
    width:150
'''

class appp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.fu = Builder.load_string(first_one)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.fu)
        thread7 = threading.Thread(target=self.running)
        thread7.start()
    def build(self):
        return self.screen
    def running(self):
        while True:
            if self.fu.text != "":
                print(self.fu.text)
            if len(self.fu.text) > 15:
                break
appp().run()
```

Comment: so, this is a completely different approach... but what does 
thread7 = threading.Thread(target=self.running)
thread7.start()
do?

Comment: this makes a minor program from the main program---you can read more about threading concept.you can chcange the MDTextField to another widget but make sure that this widget returns text from the user